# How to parse the JSON response(contains Dynamic Object-data)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

The Json response from the API is dynamic, What are the possible ways to parse the JSON data,

GSON to JSON with serialized name not possible bcz the data is dynamic.
Can anyone suggest the possible ways to parse the JSON response.

```
{
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "layout": "ListView"
  },
  "3": {
    "menu": 0,
    "id": 3,
    "layout": "DetailView"
  },
  "start": {
    "layout": "Search",
    "onClick": {
      "next": 2
    },
    "onBtnClick": {
      "next": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Where "2" or "3" can change dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic but with a finite set of known possible key/value pairs, or dynamic with an infinite set of possible key/value pairs? If the latter, I don't even understand how you could expect to intelligently parse this at all.

Comment: You should not have 2 or 3 changing dynamically. You should wonder...What is the added value of that? If you need a list of elements, use an array.

Comment: @rmlan : Its infinite set of key & value. Can i use Array or ArrayMap to store JSON object and retrieve the values. Since I know the "start" is point access data from there traverse to next object

Comment: @LoreV : Since action(2 or 3) on button click change, can you please share any link or snippet for array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the org.json library to parse the JSON "manually", which will give you direct control over what and how is parsed.

The code will look like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
//This object will have String names inside, so "2", "3", "start" etc.
JSONArray names = json.names();
for(int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(names.getString(i));
    // Inside this data variable you will have the object.
    // You can check which name it has and react accordingly
}
```

Comment: Thank You, this is one of good solution where now i have to apply some logic to store & access the json data

Comment: Great it helped you :-) If you think this is the right answer to your problem, please mark it as best answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   String key = iter.next();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You, this is one of good solution where now i have to apply some logic to store & access the json data

Answer (score 0):

With retrofit it is easy to have json response.

[Refer retrofit 2.0 for tutorial, it is very effective](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/12/retrofit-20-android-example-web.html)